# Pass flexible data in Java annotations (example: BeanValidation Payload)

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation

I would like to know which are the possibilities to pass static flexible metadatas in annotations, without having to modify them if new metadata is needed.

In my use case, I use BeanValidation annotations so I can't modify the BeanValidation annotations.

But BeanValidation provides in each class a field:

```
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
```

This Payload, in some examples, seems to be used to provide a flexible way to pass that metadata. But in the examples, this metadata is often "not flexible", for example the payload is a log level severity: [blog article](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/08/jsr-303-javaxvalidationpayload-class.html).

---

As I validate a REST API input methods. I must be able to "customize" the JSON payload on validation errors. We have a default mechanism to do so, that create an error JSON payload from ConstraintViolations, but sometimes it needs to be overridden.

I have done the following code:

```
@Data
@GreaterThan(field = "endDate", greaterThan = "startDate", strict = false, payload = EndDateMustBeGreaterThanStartDatePayload.class)
public class SomeBean {

  @Field("end_date")
  @ErrorDescription("The end date must be greater than the start date")
  public static final class EndDateMustBeGreaterThanStartDatePayload implements ApiResponseOverridePayload { };


  @NotNull
  private DateTime startDate;

  @NotNull
  @Future
  private DateTime endDate;

}
```

It works fine, but I wonder if there is not a simpler way than using annotations on an additional Class Payload.

Any idea?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what you are asking. What is your exact problem? And how do you use the payload in your example?

Comment: @Hardy on constraint violations I have code which lookup for a payload and extrats the annotations values on that payload. Just wonder if there is an alternative lighter solution to handle this.

Comment: What kind of meta-data do you actually want to propagate? For error messages, there is the `message()` attribute which is part of each Bean Validation constraint.

Comment: @Gunnar I know but this is not enough, I want to be able to set an error code + an http status for exemple

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: nop sorry, nothing better than the annotations described above